# Conditional logic on groupBy using pyspark-sql-dataframe

Tags: group-by, apache-spark-sql, conditional-statements

I have a `pyspark sql dataframe` that looks like this:

```
    id     |    code  
------------------------
|    1     |     02   |
|    1     |     03   |
|    1     |     06   |
|    2     |     02   |
|    2     |     04   |
|    2     |     02   |
|    3     |     06   |
|    3     |     04   |
```

And I am trying to get an output like this:

```
    id     |    bin   
------------------------
|    1     |     1    |
|    2     |     0    |
|    3     |     1    |
```

The logic for `bin` is that if any entry of `id` contains the `code` `03` **OR** `06` then the value of its `bin=1` else `bin=0`. For example, `id=1` has `bin=1` because some of its `code` contains `03` and `06`; `id=2` has `bin=0` because none of its `code` contains either `03` or `06`; and `id=3` has `bin=0` because one its `code` contains `03`.
I have tried using `groupBy` together with `agg` but I can only get as far as `countDistinct` or `sum` or some flavour of it. Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql import types as T
            
def bin_fxn(x):
    code = set(['03','06'])
    return 1 - int(set(x).intersection(code)==set())

def main():   

    df = sc.parallelize([[1, '02'],
                         [1, '03'],
                         [1, '06'],
                         [2, '02'],
                         [2, '04'],
                         [2, '02'],
                         [3, '06'],
                         [3, '04']]).toDF(['id', 'code'])  

    bin_def = func.udf(bin_fxn, T.IntegerType())
df.groupBy('id').agg(bin_def(func.collect_list('code')).alias('bin')).show()
    return
```

The code above achieves the goal. The use of `UDF` together with `pyspark.sql.functions` had to be made. For details visit the following [website](https://danvatterott.com/blog/2018/09/06/python-aggregate-udfs-in-pyspark/)